# Java Sequence generator service

Tags: java, cassandra, sequence

In my Neo4j project I need to expose IDs in my web application urls. I can't use internal Neo4j ids because they can be reused by Neo4j for a new nodes. I also don't want to use UUID because urls with this UUID look awful.

This is why I'm looking for a some 3rd party service that will generate unique Long identificators for my application. For example, is it possible to implement with some NoSQL storage like Cassandra and so on ? Please advice how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra does not provide Long identificators.

> UUID look awful

UUID is very good solution for decentralized systems, because each node can generate unique UUID independently. It is fast and reliable.

> is it possible to implement with some NoSQL storage

Yes, Hazelcast has own [Long Id Generator](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#idgenerator)

And as I know, other distributed in-memory data grids like Apache Ignite or Redisson have own implementation of distributed AtomicLong